# prevent string from splitting on comma when writing a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to write into a csv file 3 things :

`Restaurant,Name and Review`.

`Review` is a paragraph and contains `commas` in itself. When i write the file, I am getting the wrong output as the final csv file is splitting into columns based on the commas in the review column.

For example, if review was "food here is great, do try!" , this string value should come in one cell in the csv file.

However, csv file separates it into 2 cells, one before the comma and one after.

To counter this, I am trying to make my file `pipe` delimited.

However, I am unable to get the output. Below is my code. Please help!

```
names : list containing names of those who wrote a review
restaurant : restaurant name
review : list containing reviews

Output_File = open(restaurant+'.csv', 'w')
Output_File.write("Restaurant | Name | Review | \n")
for i in range(0, final):
    Output_File.write(restaurant + '|' + names[i] + '|' + review[i] + '\n')
Output_File.close()
```

Comment: Do you mean that the exact same code worked with commas, but now it does not work with pipes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

csv will automatically split any string on a `,` into multiple fields. In order to avoid this, you need to enclose your string containing a `,` within quotes,

```
Output_File.write('"{}","{}","{}"'.format(restaurant, names[i], review[i]))
```

This way you can still make it `,` delimited.

You can also replace `,` with any other character as a delimiter.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!